# Meteor JS - Package cannot be downloaded - HTTP error 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am stuck now for weeks with the following compiling issue. Once I start to run it on local the following error occurs.

The package cannot be downloaded since dependencies on github are down.

"https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.8.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node"

But it is not really needed and I am not sure how to skip it. The script stops here.

Please someone help. I am a junior developer.

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:xxx adam$ npm run start

> xxx-1.7@ start /Users/adam/Desktop/xxx
> meteor run --settings settings.json

[[[[[ ~/Desktop/xxx ]]]]]                 

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While loading package lookback:emails@0.7.7:
   error: Command failed:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
   rebuild --update-binary
   Cannot download
   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.8.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node": 

   HTTP error 404 Not Found

   Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
   try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

   export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

   or configure npm proxy via

   npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
   gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
   gyp verb cli [
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node',
   gyp verb cli
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
   gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
   gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
   gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
   gyp info using node@8.11.4 | darwin | x64
   gyp verb command rebuild []
   gyp verb command clean []
   gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
   gyp verb command configure []
   gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
   gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
   gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:14:12)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at F
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:69:19)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at E
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:81:29)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:90:16
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
   gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
   gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:14:12)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at F
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:69:19)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at E
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:81:29)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:90:16
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15) code:
   'ENOENT' }
   gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
   gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
   gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform;
   print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
   gyp verb get node dir compiling against specified --nodedir dev files:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle
   gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build
   gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created?
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build
   gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
   gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
   gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
   gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
   gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
   gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
   gyp info spawn args [
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
   gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
   gyp info spawn args   '-f',
   gyp info spawn args   'make',
   gyp info spawn args   '-I',
   gyp info spawn args
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
   gyp info spawn args   '-I',
   gyp info spawn args
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
   gyp info spawn args   '-I',
   gyp info spawn args
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/common.gypi',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
   gyp info spawn args
   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle',
   gyp info spawn args
   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
   gyp info spawn args
   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass',
   gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
   gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
   gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
   gyp info spawn args   'build',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
   xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer
   directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools
   instance

   xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer
   directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools
   instance

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py",
   line 16, in <module>
   sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py",
   line 545, in script_main
   return main(sys.argv[1:])
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py",
   line 538, in main
   return gyp_main(args)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py",
   line 523, in gyp_main
   generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py",
   line 2170, in GenerateOutput
   part_of_all=qualified_target in needed_targets)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py",
   line 795, in Write
   self.Pchify))
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py",
   line 1190, in WriteSources
   cflags = self.xcode_settings.GetCflags(configname)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 551, in GetCflags
   archs = self.GetActiveArchs(self.configname)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 420, in GetActiveArchs
   xcode_archs_default = GetXcodeArchsDefault()
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 118, in GetXcodeArchsDefault
   xcode_version, _ = XcodeVersion()
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 1265, in XcodeVersion
   version = re.match(r'(\d\.\d\.?\d*)', version).groups()[0]
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
   gyp ERR! configure error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
   (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
   gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
   gyp ERR! command
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
   "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
   "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
   gyp ERR! cwd
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass
   gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   Build failed
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
   logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /Users/adam/.npm/_logs/2018-10-19T19_12_17_338Z-debug.log
   Cannot download
   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.8.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node": 

   HTTP error 404 Not Found

   Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
   try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

   export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

   or configure npm proxy via

   npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
   gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
   gyp verb cli [
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node',
   gyp verb cli
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
   gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
   gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
   gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
   gyp info using node@8.11.4 | darwin | x64
   gyp verb command rebuild []
   gyp verb command clean []
   gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
   gyp verb command configure []
   gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
   gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
   gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:14:12)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at F
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:69:19)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at E
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:81:29)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:90:16
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
   gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
   gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:14:12)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at F
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:69:19)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at E
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:81:29)
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/which/which.js:90:16
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15) code:
   'ENOENT' }
   gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
   gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
   gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform;
   print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
   gyp verb get node dir compiling against specified --nodedir dev files:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle
   gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build
   gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created?
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build
   gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
   gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
   gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
   gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file:
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
   gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
   gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
   gyp info spawn args [
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
   gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
   gyp info spawn args   '-f',
   gyp info spawn args   'make',
   gyp info spawn args   '-I',
   gyp info spawn args
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
   gyp info spawn args   '-I',
   gyp info spawn args
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
   gyp info spawn args   '-I',
   gyp info spawn args
   '/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/common.gypi',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
   gyp info spawn args
   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle',
   gyp info spawn args
   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
   gyp info spawn args
   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass',
   gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
   gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
   gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
   gyp info spawn args   'build',
   gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
   xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer
   directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools
   instance

   xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer
   directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools
   instance

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py",
   line 16, in <module>
   sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py",
   line 545, in script_main
   return main(sys.argv[1:])
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py",
   line 538, in main
   return gyp_main(args)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py",
   line 523, in gyp_main
   generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py",
   line 2170, in GenerateOutput
   part_of_all=qualified_target in needed_targets)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py",
   line 795, in Write
   self.Pchify))
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py",
   line 1190, in WriteSources
   cflags = self.xcode_settings.GetCflags(configname)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 551, in GetCflags
   archs = self.GetActiveArchs(self.configname)
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 420, in GetActiveArchs
   xcode_archs_default = GetXcodeArchsDefault()
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 118, in GetXcodeArchsDefault
   xcode_version, _ = XcodeVersion()
   File
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py",
   line 1265, in XcodeVersion
   version = re.match(r'(\d\.\d\.?\d*)', version).groups()[0]
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
   gyp ERR! configure error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
   (/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
   (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
   gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
   gyp ERR! command
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
   "/Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
   "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
   "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
   gyp ERR! cwd
   /Users/adam/.meteor/packages/lookback_emails/.0.7.7.4eyw98.la2kl++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/example/node_modules/.temp-10vub78.i363/node_modules/node-sass
   gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   Build failed
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.8.0 postinstall script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
   logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /Users/adam/.npm/_logs/2018-10-19T19_12_17_338Z-debug.log


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Started MongoDB.
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message:

> npm ERR! node-sass@3.8.0

You are using version 3.8.0 of node-sass. This outdated version is incompatible with Node v8, the version of Node that you have installed.

You can either: 
1. Upgrade node-sass
2. Downgrade node to v6

I do not recommend option 2.

So, to fix this error I would recommend upgrading node-sass to at least `4.5.3`, the minimum version for Node v8. If you're using npm that would look something like `npm install node-sass@latest`.

At the time of writing, the [`@latest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass?activeTab=versions) tag will bring you to `4.9.4` and would fix this problem for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I am on, macOS mojave v10.14, node v10.12.0, npm 6.4.1, node-sass 4.9.4, libsass 3.5.4. So it should be fine.

Comment: @adamo The node version you're using according to the output you posted is v8, and node-sass 3.8.0.

Comment: very strange. because I am not on these error message versions. double check it with --version.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by the node-sass release 3.8 being removed from github, and lookback:emails package had an example app within it, that depended on this version.
We solved the problem by changing the dependency to 4.11 and also hidden the example app under .example directory, so the package itself doesn't depend on any version of node-sass any more. (Only the example app, but that is not necessary for the package to work - that is just a demo)
We pushed the fixed version to atmosphere. So you will not get the error any more once you do a `meteor update lookback:emails` to update to the latest version of the package.